# Using themes from Themeforest.net in Symfony 4.x and above

Tags: php, symfony

Is there any documentation on how to implement (convert) themes from themeforest.net to Symfony 4.x and above ?

I have a Theme with Laravel support, but no Symfony support. I would like to use the Laravel supported theme and convert it for Symfony.

Answer (score 0):

No it doesn't exist. Actually, it shouldn't be so hard to "convert" a Laravel theme to Symfony theme, because they are not really sliced as Wordpress do.

Themes are all made from HTML, CSS and JS.
Developers use a specific logic (different for each framework/CMS) to split the HTML to fit the framework/CMS logic.

A Wordpress theme is really sliced into different section which make it really hard to convert.

But Laravel and Symfony don't use a specific logic for their view. You have to build your own.

Laravel use [Blade](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/views) for rendering and Symfony use [Twig](https://twig.symfony.com/) which are similar.